# Как вывести на smarty из переменной с контентом только текст (PrestaShop)?

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

К примеру в smarty шаблонах у PrestaShop 1.7, есть переменная `{$product.description_short|truncate:500:'...' nofilter}`, в которой может содержаться не только текст, но и любой другой графический контент. Как вывести только текст в тэгах `<p>Текст</p>`, или без?

Comment: `{...|strip_tags}` добавьте, останется текст

Comment: Так добавьте в ответ. Зачту.